# PyQt MVC pasar objetos entre controladores

Tags: python, mvc, pyqt

Tengo una aplicación donde intento seguir el concepto Modelo-Vista-Controlador. El controlador 1 obtiene el doble del valor introducido y el controlador 2 obtiene el cuadrado del valor obtenido en el controlador 1.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que no consigo pasar el valor obtenido en el controlador 1 al controlador 2.

Dejo el código

**vista.pyw**

```
import sys

from mainwin import *
from controlador1 import Controlador1
from controlador2 import Controlador2

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.cnt1 = Controlador1(self)
        self.cnt2 = Controlador2(self)

        self.line = self.ui.lineEdit
        self.button1 = self.ui.pushButton1
        self.button2 = self.ui.pushButton2
        self.lbl1 = self.ui.label_resultado1
        self.lbl2 = self.ui.label_resultado2

        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.cnt1.resultado1)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.cnt2.resultado2)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Window()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**controlador1.py**

```
from modelo1 import Modelo1

class Controlador1:

    def __init__(self, ventana):

        self.vnt = ventana

    def resultado1(self):

        val = float(self.vnt.line.text())
        self.mod1 = Modelo1(val)
        valor = self.mod1.doble()
        self.vnt.lbl1.setText(str(valor))
```

**controlador2.py**

```
from modelo2 import Modelo2

    class Controlador2:

        def __init__(self, ventana):

            self.vnt = ventana

        def resultado2(self):

            # Aquí no sé como incorporar los datos de controlador1.
```

**modelo1.py**

```
class Modelo1:

    def __init__(self, x):

        self.x = x

    def doble(self):

        return self.x * 2
```

**modelo2.py**

```
class Modelo2:

    def __init__(self, y):

        self.y = y

    def cuadrado(self):

        return self.y ** 2
```

Comment: en la funcion resultado de controlador 2 usa la ventanda: `def resultado2(self): valor = float(self.vnt.lbl1.text())`

Comment: Gracias. ¿Y si el dato que quiero importar no aparece en la ventana de PyQt ? En mi caso real tengo en controlador1 un DataFrame de pandas con el que quiero continuar trabajando en controlador2.

Comment: Si deseas ayuda provee un [mcve]

Comment: Vale. Para no mezclar he abierto un [nuevo post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243292/pyqt-mvc-pasar-objetos-entre-controladores-2) indicando otro ejemplo de código.