# PyQt MVC pasar objetos entre controladores (2)

Tags: python, mvc, pyqt

Como complemento a mi [primera pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/242087/pyqt-mvc-pasar-objetos-entre-controladores) sobre el tema hago esta segunda consulta introduciendo un nuevo código para diferenciarlo mejor de el de la primera consulta.

Tengo un código organizado en diferentes controladores. En el controlador1 tengo un `DataFrame` de `pandas` obtenido de una fuente de datos, puede ser también un objeto cualquiera. De este `DataFrame` obtengo unos datos que muestro en una ventana de PyQt.

En el controlador2 necesito acceder a este mismo `DataFrame` para obtener otros resultados. ¿Cómo paso este objeto a controlador2?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**vista.pyw**

```
import sys

from mainwin import *
from controlador1 import Controlador1
from controlador2 import Controlador2


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.cnt1 = Controlador1(self)
        self.cnt2 = Controlador2(self)

        self.button_max = self.ui.pushButton_valor_maximo
        self.button_min = self.ui.pushButton_valor_minimo
        self.lbl_max = self.ui.label_valor_maximo
        self.lbl_min = self.ui.label_valor_minimo

        self.button_max.clicked.connect(self.cnt1.resultado1)
        self.button_min.clicked.connect(self.cnt2.resultado2)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Window()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**controlador1.py**

```
import pandas as pd

class Controlador1:

    def __init__(self, ventana):

        self.vnt = ventana
        # pandas DataFrame obtenido de sql, csv...
        self.df = pd.DataFrame({
            'a': [1, -3, 5],
            'b': [-2, 4, -6]
        })

    def resultado1(self):

        valor_max = self.df['a'].max()
        self.vnt.lbl_max.setText(str(valor_max))
```

**controlador2.py**

```
class Controlador2:

    def __init__(self, ventana):

        self.vnt = ventana
        # ¿Cómo paso aquí self.df del controlador1?

    def resultado2(self):

        valor_min = self.df['b'].min()
        self.vnt.lbl_min.setText(str(valor_min))
```

**EDITADO**

Modifico el código según el comentario de @eyllanesc. Saco la lectura del `DataFrame` de `pandas` del controlador1 y la meto en un modelo.

**controlador1.py**

```
from modelo import Modelo

class Controlador1:

    def __init__(self, ventana):

        self.vnt = ventana
        self.modelo = Modelo()

    def resultado1(self):

        valor_max = self.modelo.valor_max()
        self.vnt.lbl_max.setText(str(valor_max))
```

**controlador2.py**

```
from modelo import Modelo

class Controlador2:

    def __init__(self, ventana):

        self.vnt = ventana
        self.modelo = Modelo()

    def resultado2(self):

        valor_min = self.modelo.valor_min()
        self.vnt.lbl_min.setText(str(valor_min))
```

**modelo.py**

```
import pandas as pd

class Modelo:

    def __init__(self):

        # pandas DataFrame obtenido de sql, csv...
        self.df = pd.DataFrame({
            'a': [1, -3, 5],
            'b': [-2, 4, -6]
        })

    def valor_max(self):

        valor_max = self.df['a'].max()
        return valor_max

    def valor_min(self):

        valor_min = self.df['b'].min()
        return valor_min
```

Comment: ¿donde esta tu modelo? ¿no crees que en tu modelo debe estar el dataframe?,  los controladores deben tener la referencia al modelo, y asi al df sera accesible por los controladores a traves del modelo

Comment: Ya entiendo @eyllanesc. He modificado el código según tu comentario y de esta forma ya puedo acceder a la información del `DataFrame` desde cada controlador.

Comment: hay un error en tu codigo, al hacer `self.modelo = Modelo()` estas creando un nuevo modelo y en tu codigo hay 2 de esas instruciones que implica tener 2 modelos, en vez de ello te recomiendo pasar el modelo como has pasado la ventana al controlador

Comment: He probado lo que recomiendas @eyllanesc, aunque no tengo claro que sea exactamente lo que dices. En `vista.pyw` importo el modelo con `from modelo import Modelo` e instancio el objeto en `class Window(...): def __init__(...): self.mdl = Modelo()`. Ya dentro de los controladores me refiero al modelo de la forma `valor_max = self.vnt.mdl.valor_max()`.